# Global IAsyncPageFilter not hitting breakpoint for asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, filter, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently using the IAsyncPageFilter sample that has been provided by Microsoft but it doesn't seem to be hitting a breakpoint in either OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync or CompletedTask. I'm wanting every request through every controller/action to go through a method to store some stats before continuing on with the request.

It's an .NET Core MVC application.

Microsoft Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Code:

```
public class SampleAsyncPageFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
{

    public Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context,
                                                  PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {         
        // Do post work.
        await next.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        //services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddRazorPages()
         .AddMvcOptions(options =>
         {
             options.Filters.Add(new SampleAsyncPageFilter());
         });

    
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        //app.UseStaticFiles();

        AzureUserContext.Tenant_Id = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetSection("Domain").Value;
        AzureUserContext.Client_Id = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetSection("ClientId").Value;
        AzureUserContext.Client_Secret = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C").GetSection("ClientSecret").Value;

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = context =>
            {
                // Cache static file for 1 year
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Context.Request.Query["v"]))
                {
                    context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("cache-control", new[] { "public,max-age=2628000" });
                    context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", new[] { DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1).ToString("R") }); // Format RFC1123
                }
            }
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: A Page Filter doesn't run for Controllers/Actions: it runs only for Pages. Perhaps you need a [Resource Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#resource-filters)?

Comment: That worked thank you. I'll post my full solution later. Thanks again.